# FFmpeg NVENC rtsp stream encoding freezes randomly

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, streaming, nvenc

In some executions of the following command, ffmpeg freezes at certain time and after some minutes starts to encode the stream again. The problem don't happen always. The stream server is an avigilon camera.

```
 ffmpeg -hwaccel cuda -hex -rtsp_transport tcp -t 60 -i rtsp://user:passwd@ip/defaultPrimary?streamType=u -c:v h264_nvenc -s:v 1080x720 -dn -an -b:v 2.4M -maxrate 2.4M -bufsize 1M -profile:v high
-pix_fmt yuv420p -preset llhq -qmin:v 19 -qmax:v 21 out.mp4
```

See the log when it freezes:

[image]

**Am I doing something wrong?This is a known bug?There is a work around solution?**

**ffmpeg version**: N-91936-g776cdd1dc8 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)

**CUDA toolkit version**: 9.2

**NVidia driver**: nvidia-396